Connection refused on some ports (not firewall related)
EDIT - TLDR - couldnt fix this and ended up removing sabnzbdplus and nextcloud from snap and clean install directly to make it work.
ORIGINAL POST
I have a problem in which mydomain.com:xxx is not working for certain ports but it does for others. The offending port is 25915
Here is the output of netstat -at :
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:43471         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 mydomain.com:25915  0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:36063         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:tproxy          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:32600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8989            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 _localdnsstub:domain    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 _localdnsproxy:domain   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        1      0 mydomain.com:41706  104.18.1.127:https      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 localhost:47160         localhost:36063         CLOSE_WAIT
tcp       25      0 mydomain.com:56934  ec2-63-32-160-109:https CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 mydomain.com:41548  ec2-52-210-137-28:https CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        1      0 mydomain.com:41688  104.18.1.127:https      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 mydomain.com:25915  mydomain.com:32916  TIME_WAIT
tcp       25      0 mydomain.com:43112  ec2-52-210-137-28:https CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 mydomain.com:41040  pubsub08.pop.lhr.:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 mydomain.com:41698  104.18.1.127:https      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 mydomain.com:25915  mydomain.com:32906  TIME_WAIT
tcp        1      0 mydomain.com:59896  104.18.0.127:https      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5353               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7878               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:32400              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9090               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 mydomain.com:ssh    192.168.0.148:51878     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 mydomain.com:32400  106.75.154.180:24084    TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0    116 mydomain.com:ssh    192.168.0.148:50670     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 mydomain.com:32400  106.75.154.180:24738    TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 mydomain.com:https  185.224.128.74:22956    TIME_WAIT

Here is the output of ufw status :
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
32400/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
9090/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8989/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7878/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
25915/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
25915/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
25915                      ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
32400/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8989/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7878/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25915/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25915/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25915 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Here is the output of wget localhost:25915 :
--2024-07-02 04:41:57--  http://localhost:25915/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:25915... failed: Connection refused.

Here is the output of wget localhost:7878 :
--2024-07-02 04:42:36--  http://localhost:7878/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:7878... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.5’

index.html.5                      [ <=>                                              ]   1.85K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2024-07-02 04:42:36 (93.6 MB/s) - ‘index.html.5’ saved [1898]

UPDATE:
I have checked to see what is listening on port 25915 and got the following process:
/usr/bin/python3 -OO /usr/bin/sabnzbdplus --daemon --pidfile /var/run/sabnzbdplus/pid --server localhost:25915
